# Stored procedure not saving decimal number as expected

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I declare a decimal variable

```
@Limit decimal
```

I pass a value of 200.5 from a C# application and insert this value with a normal, very basic insert statement into a table. The value is saved as 201.00, it seems like the value is rounded up for some reason.

The type of limit is decimal(10,2), any idea why this would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without declaring exact precision and scale your `@Limit` variable has decimal(18,0) type by default.
Declare it as `declare @Limit decimal(10,2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the precision and scale in the parameter declaration - the default is 18,0

```
 @Limit decimal(10,2)
```